# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||=' while running Vitest testcase

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia, vitest, vuetifyjs3

As part of executing the Vitest test cases, I found multiple issues and fixed one after another but not able to find proper solution for this because I could not find **'||='** in my entire project and I am not sure from there it's picking.

Previously, I had the issue of **localStorage is not defined**, for that I have added the below piece of code in **vite.config.ts** file.

```
type: {
   globals: true,
   environment: 'jsdom'
}
```

Then, I started facing this issue. Could you please anyone suggest me how should I fix this issue? Any reference project for Vitest test cases with the technology of Vue3+Vuetify3+Pinia is more helpful. Thanks
[image: vite.config.ts]
[image: error log]

Comment: Which is you node version?

Comment: note that is required at least NodeJS v15 in order to  use that operator, maybe it is being used in one of the packages you are using

Comment: Node 14.17.x version we are using

Comment: so, thats the issue, did you try running at least Node 15.x.x or above?